# Certificate Friendly Name

Tags: c++, certificate, cryptoapi

I am attempting to set the friendly name on a certificate when I store that certificate on a machine with the following code:

```
CRYPT_DATA_BLOB fName = {_tcslen(FriendlyName) * sizeof(TCHAR), FriendlyName};
CertSetCertificateContextProperty(certContext, CERT_FRIENDLY_NAME_PROP_ID, 0, &fName));
```

Where, obviously, FriendlyName is an LPWSTR pointing to the friendly name and certContext is the valid certificate context from saving the certificate in the store.  The function works correctly and the name is written into the certificate.  However, when I view it in the certificate snap-in, the last letter of the name is truncated.  I have tried adding one to the length of the name and that ends up cutting the name in half.  I have checked FriendlyName and the length to ensure they are correct and they are.  If I change FriendlyName to an LPSTR, it shows up as Kanjii characters.  In an example provided by Microsoft, they do the following:

```
BYTE *pName = (BYTE *)"Temp Name.";
CRYPT_DATA_BLOB  Friendly_Name_Blob={32,pName};
```

I have no idea where they get the 32 from, nor do they provide an explanation that I can find.  When I use 32, it again truncates the name.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong and how to correct it?

Answer (score 1):

To set `CERT_FRIENDLY_NAME_PROP_ID` property using [CertSetCertificateContextProperty](http://preview.library.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you need first initialize `CRYPT_DATA_BLOB` and then use it as the last parameter of `CertSetCertificateContextProperty`. The code could be about the following:

```
LPWSTR pszFriendlyName = L"My test friendly name";
CRYPT_DATA_BLOB cryptBlob;
BOOL bResult;

cryptBlob.cbData = (lstrlenW(pszFriendlyName) + 1)*sizeof(WCHAR);
cryptBlob.pbData = (PBYTE)pszFriendlyName;

// pCertContext should be set before
bResult = CertSetCertificateContextProperty (pCertContext,
                                             CERT_FRIENDLY_NAME_PROP_ID,
                                             0, (LPVOID)&cryptBlob);
if (!bResult) {
    // error
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing.  If you use the length of the friendly name + 1 for cbData, the string gets truncated to about half its length.

Comment: @DrewBurchett: In the second part of you question you used `(BYTE *)"Temp Name."` instead of Unicode string and used some unclear constant `32` for the data size in bytes. The code which I posted I get from my old working program. So it's really work if you just use correct string format and specify correct length of data.

Comment: The second set of source code is pulled directly from an example on Microsoft's site.  The first set of source code (which is exactly  like yours) is what I'm attempting to use in my code.

Comment: @DrewBurchett: Do you tried the code which I posted? Could you verify that it works? Is it not what you want?

Comment: Yes.  When using lstrlenw() + 1, the Friendly name in the certificate is truncated to about half its length.

Comment: @DrewBurchett: Sorry, but you should be more carefully next time if you write such comments. I wrote test program and all works perfect. I suppose that you forget to use `*sizeof(WCHAR)` (see the code of my answer). The size in byte of the data which you set in `cbData` should be `(lstrlenw(...) + 1)*sizeof(WCHAR)`. If you would not use `*sizeof(WCHAR)` you would have a half its length.

Comment: @DrewBurchett: Do you have success now?

Comment: Maybe you forgot the brackets - when you say adding 1 cuts the string in half, that sounds like you're doing `lstrlenw(...) + 1 * sizeof(WCHAR)` which results in `lstrlenw(...) + (1 * sizeof(WCHAR))`, not what you want, which is `(lstrlenw(...) + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR)`

Comment: @DaveBrotherstone: Sorry, but I don't understand exactly which code you use which produce any problem. What I wrote: 1) one should use UNICODE data as the value of `cryptBlob.pbData` binary blob. 2) the binary data should include L'\0' (two bytes) at the end of the string: `cryptBlob.cbData = (lstrlenW(pszFriendlyName) + 1)*sizeof(WCHAR);`. If you would use `cryptBlob` constructed in the way you will use `CertSetCertificateContextProperty` with `CERT_FRIENDLY_NAME_PROP_ID` successfully.

Comment: @Oleg, I don't have a problem, it works perfectly when cbdata includes the null as you say, I was only suggesting that the OP's problem with the string being cut in half could be due to operator precedence if he didn't bracket it properly.

Comment: @DaveBrotherstone: I'm sure that the described problem (the string being cut in half) was because or setting wrong value for `cbData`: length in characters instead of the length in bytes (it doesn't matter which code was posted in the text of the question)